# Python initialize a dictionary with condition values

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements

When I initialize the `check_dict`, will all the values(condition) be calculated(become boolean values), if yes will it be not efficient if I put conditon be dictionary's value, is there any better way to do it?

```
def checker(fruit: str, number: int) -> bool:
    check_dict = {
        "apple": True if number > 3 else False,
        "banana": True if number < 2 else False,
        "watermelon": True if number > 10 else False
    }
    res = check_dict.get(fruit, None)
    if res:
        return res

ans = checker(fruit="apple", number=4)
print(ans)
```

Comment: Just a note, CCing @AndrejKesely, both `checker1` (in @AndrejKesely answer) and `checker3` (in my answer) are not equivalent functions to `checker2` (which is the same as original `checker`): they return different results. For example, take `checker('apple', 0)`. This code at the end of your function - `if res: return res` - makes your function to always return either `True` or `None` and never return `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why construct a dictionary? Simple `if-else` is enough:

```py
def checker(fruit: str, number: int) -> bool:
    if fruit == "apple":
        return number > 3
    elif fruit == "banana":
        return number < 2
    elif fruit == "watermelon":
        return number > 10


ans = checker(fruit="apple", number=4)
print(ans)
```

---

EDIT: Small benchmark:

```py
from timeit import timeit


def checker1(fruit: str, number: int) -> bool:
    if fruit == "apple":
        return number > 3
    elif fruit == "banana":
        return number < 2
    elif fruit == "watermelon":
        return number > 10


def checker2(fruit: str, number: int) -> bool:
    check_dict = {
        "apple": True if number > 3 else False,
        "banana": True if number < 2 else False,
        "watermelon": True if number > 10 else False,
    }
    res = check_dict.get(fruit, None)
    if res:
        return res


t1 = timeit('checker1("watermelon", 4)', number=1_000_000, globals=globals())
t2 = timeit('checker2("watermelon", 4)', number=1_000_000, globals=globals())

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints:

```
0.10748997700284235
0.23576407400832977
```

Comment: faster? using dictionary for mapping the result directly

Comment: @tung I've edited the question and put there small benchmark. The `if-else` solution is ~2x faster. It's because constructing the dictionary takes too much time.

Comment: Thank you so much, if the time for constructing the dictionary is so much larger then if else, then I think if else maybe the best way to do it

Comment: I am not sure about the underneath during constructing the dictionary, but I guess it need to calculate all condition solution when initialize the dictionary base on the time spent

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a little bit shorter. `get` method of dict has `None` as default value if key doesn't exists

```
def checker(fruit: str, number: int) -> bool:
    check_dict = {
        "apple": number > 3,
        "banana": number < 2,
        "watermelon": number > 10
    }
    res = check_dict.get(fruit)
    if res:
        return res

ans = checker(fruit="apple", number=4)
print(ans)
```

Comment: Even shorter `return fruit == "apple" and number > 3 or fruit == "banana" and number < 2 or fruit == "watermelon" and number > 10`

Answer (score 0):

If the `checker` function is intended to be called repeatedly and maybe the list of fruits is larger, one way of optimizing this is to pull the dictionary creation outside of the `checker` function like this:

```
check_dict = {
    "apple": lambda x: x > 3,
    "banana": lambda x: x < 2,
    "watermelon": lambda x: x > 10,
}

def checker3(fruit: str, number: int) -> bool:
    return check_dict.get(fruit)(number)
```

Comment: I tested it and compare the time with if-else, seems if-else is still faster than this

Comment: @tung Yes it is, very slightly. That is why I mentioned the number of fruits in my answer. For 3 fruits, `if-else` is the obvious choice. Try writing an `if-else` for 50 choices. Just add 2-3 more fruits to your list and redo your timing tests for the last fruit in the `if-else` block and report your findings. Add 7+ fruits to your list and _on average_ this approach will be faster than `if-else` approach.